# Reference for Math-Physics history book

Tags: physics, math-history

I am looking for a book on history of mathematics that would also serve as a book on history of physics. In the sense that the history of math is developed along with the developments in physics during the time and explaining some influences both ways. Or the other way, a book that develops the history of physics also with the developments in math would be great too.

Many thanks in advance for all your suggestions!

Comment: Perhaps helps https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks! I have posted it in hsm.stackexchange.com too.

Comment: I am also interested in this subject.

Answer (score 0):

A book that comes to mind immediately would be Issac Assimov's "The history of physics", a history of how physics developed, which inevitably also talks about the history of mathematics. Its also an easy read, without being too clunky. Strongle recomend it.

Another one that I very strongly recomend is Issac Newtons "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", a.k.a Principia. It states Newtons laws of motion and gravitation, as well as delving into Kepler's laws of planetary motion. This one is more physics oriented, but if youre familiar with Newton you'll know that he also developed the field of calculus, something which is reflected in Principia.